# three simple question about Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$  is a Banach space, and its closed unit ball is separable, then do we know that $X$ is separable?

If $X$  is a separable Banach space, then do we know that its closed unit ball is separable?

If $X$  is a Banach space, and its unit sphere is separable, then do we know that $X$ is separable too?

A topological space is separable if it has a countably dense subset.

This isn't obvious to me.

Comment: For the second one, for any set $S$ that is countable and dense in $X$, $S\cap B$ is countable and dense in the closed unit ball $B$.

Comment: (note that [it is also true for the open unit ball](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352581/is-the-unit-ball-of-a-separable-banach-space-itself-separable), although it is not as straightforward.)

Comment: @Cement C.I know that any open subset of a separable space is separable, but for the closed subset?

Comment: See the comment above: take your favorite dense and countable subset S$ in $X$, and show it is dense in the closed unit ball as well.

Comment: A metric space is separable if and only if it is second countable. Second countability passes to subspaces.The second is trival.

Comment: Just consider the closure of the open ball, if the open ball is separable, the closure of the open ball is also separable.

Comment: @ Tryss the clourse of a separable subset is also separable, in general?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is dense in $X$ if $X \subset \bar{A}$. But $\bar{X}$ is the smallest closed set such that $X\subset \bar{X}$, so $\bar{X} \subset \bar{A}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes in the 3 cases.

- For the first one, consider the subset

$$\bigcup_{n\geq 1} nE$$

Where E is a countable dense subset of the unit ball.

Now you can show it's dense in all of X (basically, if you have a point x, you just have to show it can be approached by points of $(\lfloor \|x\| \rfloor +1)E$ )

- For the second one, just consider $E\cap \bar{B}(0,1)$ and you can show it's dense in $\bar{B}(0,1)$
- For the last one, consider the subset

$$\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} qE$$

Where E is a countable dense subset of the unit sphere.

Now you can show it's dense in all of X. Take a sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ that converge to $\|x\|$ and a sequence of the spere that converge to $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and it's easy to construct a sequence that converge to x