# Separable Bnach space implies that the unit ball is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, separable-spaces

if someone could give me an idea of ​​how to carry out this demonstration I would greatly appreciate it, let E be a Banach space, demonstrate

E is separables $\Rightarrow$ The closed unit ball $B_E=\{x∈E:||x||≤1\}$ is separables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the unit ball of a separable Banach space itself separable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352581/is-the-unit-ball-of-a-separable-banach-space-itself-separable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a countable dense subset of $E$. Then for every positive rational $r\le 1$, $A_r'=\{\frac{ra}{\|a\|}\mid a\in A\}$ is countable and dense on the sphere of radius $r$. Then the union $\cup_r A_r'$ is a countable dense subset of the unit ball.

Comment: Please do not answer questions without context. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: This question does have context, at least for me. Apparently, as FreeHongKong pointed out, this is an exact copy of another question on this site which also has answer.